# Spark Streaming Dataset<Row> collectAsList() taking too much time

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I've done a Spark Streaming (2.1.1) driver in Java to compute logs and update the stats in a MySQL table, inserting or updating the existing rows with the rows comming in the streaming batch.
It would be great if I could use Dataset Write() method but I cant because there are just two ways:
- SaveMode.Append: only for new rows
- SaveMode.Overwrite: not valid beacuse it deletes the whole table so only rows comming in the batch are save

(I  wish there was a "SaveMode.Update" ...)

I've managed the situation by processing the dataset fetching all the rows and inserting/updating manually one by one:
*   Dataset dataToWrite
    List rows = dataToWrite.collectAsList();
    for (Row row : rows) {
        .... insert/update the table
    }*

and this works fine, the problem I'm facing is that "collectAsList()" is taking up to 2s each Rdd execution to be processed, I've seen this in Spark Console (SQL), I supposed this is due to the time in collect data (executed in Master), but it is strange beacuse it happens either if I have one Master and two Workers in the same machine or in different.
Is someone facing this problem? does anyone have any thoughts to avoid this?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but there is a project in the spark ecosystem that extends the dataframe API so you can write DF.update(....) as you indicated. Unfortunately you would have to import your MySQL data into it as it contains its own database. But it would avoid collectAsList entirely. See [SnappyData](https://github.com/SnappyDataInc/snappydata)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'll have a look to that project but I'm afraid importing data to other database is not an option since there are other pieces reading from MySQL in pseudo real-time to show the stats.